# Why did my Preloader begin loading indefinetly?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, preloader

The preloader I implemented into my website is loading indefinitely. It keeps loading and never goes to the homepage of the website and I'm not really sure what the issue is as the problem started without me seemingly changing anything.

The HTML Code for the preloader:

```
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,200,400,300,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,600,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--
            CSS
            ============================================= -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/linearicons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nice-select.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/animate/animate.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/css-hamburgers/hamburgers.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/animsition/css/animsition.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/select2/select2.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/util.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/maincontact.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Start Preloader Area -->
    <div class="preloader-area">
        <div class="loader-box">
            <div class="loader"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Preloader Area -->
```

Javascript:

```
 //------- Pre Loader --------//  
    $(window).on('load', function () {
        $(".preloader-area").delay(200).fadeOut(500);
    })
```

That's the only code that's been touched at all between now and when the preloader started loading indefinitely. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Please provide more details as to how you are showing/hiding preloader.

Comment: Thank you for Pointing this out. I added the javascript aswell.

Comment: Your window .on load function is not being executed. Make sure you have included jquery file above this script. This may help -  window load inside ready state may not be triggered. - https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3194. Also - <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/animsition/css/animsition.min.css"> - Is this right? Or spelling mistake in word - animation?

Comment: That worked actually. Thank you!